# The equation $x^3-3x+1=0 $ has 3 real roots $ a,b,c$ where $ a <b <c$. What is the value of $\{a\}+\{b\}+\{c\}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Use of calculator is not allowed. The symbol $\{x\} $ means the fractional part of $x$.

I have drawn the graph and found the greatest integer part of the roots but am having trouble finding the fractional parts

Comment: You are asked to find $\{ a\} + \{ b\} + \{ c\}$, not $\{ a\}$ ,$ \{ b\} $ or $ \{ c\}$.

Comment: All roots aren't real. See [this](http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2B3x-1+roots&x=13&y=5).

Comment: @Roby5: or, without WA, the derivative  $3x^2+3$ has no real roots.

Comment: I amExtremely sorry i made a mistake typing it i corrected it right now

Comment: Wait, how are we supposed to find $\lbrace x\rbrace$?

Comment: When 0<x<1 do you define the fractional part of x as x or -1-x?

Comment: @user254665 Why would you approach it as $-1-x$?  for $x>0$, I'd define it as $\lbrace x\rbrace:=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$

Comment: @Simple Art. See the comments following the answer from Akash Bajaj.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ = $x^3-3x+1$. Now see that:

$f(-2)=-1$, $f(-1)=3$, $f(0)=1$, $f(1)=-1$ and $f(2)=3$. Then the three roots will be such that

$-2<a<-1$, $0<b<1$ and $1<c<2$. Thus $[a]=-2$, $[b]=0$ and $[c]=1$. Now -

$\lbrace{a\rbrace}+\lbrace{b\rbrace}+\lbrace{c\rbrace}=(a+b+c)-([a]+[b]+[c])$

$(a+b+c)$ denotes the sum of roots of our cubic equation, which in general is given as "minus times the coefficient of $x^2$ divided by the coefficient of $x^3$ in the cubic equation". (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas))  Since, the coefficient of $x^2$ is $0$, thus the sum of roots is zero. And therefore -

$\lbrace{a\rbrace}+\lbrace{b\rbrace}+\lbrace{c\rbrace}=(a+b+c)-([a]+[b]+[c])=0-(-2+0+1)=1.$

**Note**: Just to mention, I used definition (2) as given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalPart.html) . If someone wants to use definition (1), then instead of writing fractional part of $a$ as $a-[a]$, write it as $a-Ceiling(a)$ (using wolfram notation as given [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ceiling.html)), where $Ceiling(a)$ will be $-1$ and the final answer would be $0$.

Comment: You can use \$\lbrace\$ and \$\rbrace\$.

Comment: @SimpleArt - Thanks! :D

Comment: Ok... I'll include that...

Comment: I am worried about how you define the fractional part of $a$..., it doesn't seem as though that is how you should take the fractional part of a negative number.

Comment: Please can you explain the last step . Why is a+b+c=0

Comment: @SimpleArt - There is definitely some confusion regarding the definition of fractional part. Refer: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalPart.html. I used the "Graham et. al. definition". But as the page says: "Unfortunately, there is no universal agreement on the meaning of frac(x) for x<0" :\

Comment: But as we do not know a,b,c how will we know a-[a] etc. .?

Comment: @Studyinghard - Sure we do not know each of them individually. But we know their sum (as is mentioned in the answer). We also know each of their greatest integer parts (denoted by $[a]$).  Thus, we know the sum of their greatest integer parts as well. This is enough to calculate the sum of their fractional parts. Since we need only the sum of their fractional parts, we do not require $a-[a]$, $b-[b]$ and $c-[c]$ individually.

Comment: @akashBajaj  thank you so much for your help